# ionic navbar change from opacity transition 0 to 1

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework

`$scope.getPosition = function () {
    //Toast.show($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top,'top');
    if ($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top > 40) {
      $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(true);
    } else {
      $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(false);
    }
  };`
[bar color opacity 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUYNn.jpg) [bar color white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFzAt.png)

when I scroll to bottom slow, the header bar gradually becomes white from the transparent color

thank in advance!!!

Comment: What code or techniques have you tried so far?

Comment: i just try to show or hide  no transition

Comment: $scope.getPosition = function () {
    //Toast.show($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top,'top');
    if ($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top > 40) {
      $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(true);
    } else {
      $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(false);
    }
  };